# After converting to exe an error appears: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, exe

I ran a Python program and everything worked great, after converting to an exe file, when I try to run it gives an error like this:
`ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.`

I don't understand where the problem is